# Is $\mathbb Q \times \{0\}$ an integral domain?

Tags: ring-theory, integral-domain

Is $\mathbb Q \times \{0\}$ an integral domain?

I understand that $\mathbb Q \times \{0\}$ is a commutative ring with unity.
But there was no clear proof that it has no zero divisor.

How do I prove $\mathbb Q \times \{0\}$ is a zero divisor, if it's true that $\mathbb Q \times \{0\}$ is an integral domain?

Comment: Isn't $\Bbb Q\times\{0\}\cong\Bbb Q$?

Comment: Q x {0},' x' means cartesian product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(a,0)\ne (0,0)$ and $(b,0)\cdot (a,0)=(ba,0)=(0,0)$, then $ba=0$ and $a\ne 0$, and therefore $b=0$.

Comment: Why are we taking "a" not equal to 0.

Comment: Because $(a,b)\ne (c,b)$ if and only if $a\ne c$.

Comment: No. What I am asking is why did you write $(a,0)\ne (0,0)$?

Comment: Because I want to prove that the ring is an integral domain, and being an integral domain means that non-zero elements aren't zero divisors.

Comment: Ok. I think i got this. Thanks